# Python - getting values from 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array:

```
[[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]
```

How do I call a value from it? For example I want to `print (name + " " + type)` and get

> shotgun weapon

I can't find a way to do so. Somehow `print list[2][1]` outputs nothing, not even errors.

Comment: if you're naming your structure "list", be careful, as list is a reserved word in python.

Comment: "I have a 2d array" No you don't, you have ragged nested arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'f
ood'], []]
>>> print mylist[2][1]
weapon
```

Remember a couple of things,

1. don't name your list, [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list)... it's a python reserved word
2. lists start at index 0. so `mylist[0]` would give `[]`
   similarly, `mylist[1][0]` would give `'shotgun'`
3. consider alternate data structures like [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Would use dictionaries if I didn't plan to add other things into these lists. For example if I have ["shotgun", "weapon", "common"] it is no longer a pair :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Accessing through index works with any `sequence` `(String, List, Tuple)`: -

```
>>> list1 = [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]
>>> list1[1]
['shotgun', 'weapon']
>>> print list1[1][1]
weapon
>>> print ' '.join(list1[1])
shotgun weapon
>>>
```

You can use **join** on the list, to get String out of list..

Comment: Why a down vote?? Do I deserve a comment here from the downvoter??

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]
print " ".join(array[1])
```

slice into the array with the `[1]`, then join the contents of the array using `' '.join()`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [80]: [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]
Out[80]: [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]

In [81]: a = [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]

In [82]: a[1]
Out[82]: ['shotgun', 'weapon']

In [83]: a[2][1]
Out[83]: 'weapon'
```

For getting all the list elements, you should use for loop as below.

```
In [89]: a
Out[89]: [[], ['shotgun', 'weapon'], ['pistol', 'weapon'], ['cheesecake', 'food'], []]

In [90]: for item in a:
    print " ".join(item)
   ....:     

shotgun weapon
pistol weapon
cheesecake food
```